# Python - Extracting a Smaller Matrix from a Larger one

Tags: python, matrix

I'm trying to extract a particular 5x5 matrix from a 11x5 matrix in Python. Does anyone know what the best way to do this would be? Thanks.

Edit: This is what I have.

```
   [[ 1.0, 0.0, -0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, -0.1, -0.1, 0.3, -0.2, -0.3],
    [ 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, -1.1, -0.6, 1.6, -1.2, -0.4],
    [ 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, -2.0, -1.5, 2.7, -2.1, -0.8],
    [-0.0, -0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 5.0, -0.6, -0.7, 0.9, -0.5, -0.6],
    [-0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, 1.0, 6.0, 0.0, -0.3, -0.4, 0.4, -0.2]]
```

And I would like to make a matrix out of the last five columns.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] of what you have already tried. Also, a little more detail about what you want to do.

Comment: Where's the code you have written? or you have no idea how to start? For hint, make a method submatrix which takes row,col from which you want to start. Then you just loop over and keep appending to a new grid.

Comment: I hope there's a comma after each list of row.

Comment: What are you using? Basic python list-of-lists? Numpy? Pandas?

Answer (score 2):

Using **Numpy**. Extracting any size submatrix from any matrix.

```
def submatrix( matrix, startRow, startCol, size):
    return x[startRow:startRow+size,startCol:startCol+size]
```

**Test:**

```
>>>>import numpy as np
>>> a = [[ 1.0, 0.0, -0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, -0.1, -0.1, 0.3, -0.2, -0.3],
...     [ 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, -1.1, -0.6, 1.6, -1.2, -0.4],
...     [ 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, -2.0, -1.5, 2.7, -2.1, -0.8],
...     [-0.0, -0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 5.0, -0.6, -0.7, 0.9, -0.5, -0.6],
...     [-0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, 1.0, 6.0, 0.0, -0.3, -0.4, 0.4, -0.2]]
>>> 
>>> x = np.array(a)
>>> def submatrix(matrix, startRow, startCol, size):
...     return matrix[startRow:startRow+size,startCol:startCol+size]
... 
>>> print submatrix(a, 2, 4, 5)
[[ 0.   4.  -2.  -1.5  2.7]
 [ 0.   5.  -0.6 -0.7  0.9]
 [ 1.   6.   0.  -0.3 -0.4]]
```

As the starting row here was 2 it print only 3 rows.

Answer (score 1):

Without numpy:

```
[row[-5:] for row in matrix]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the matrix into a `numpy` array (assuming it is a basic list-of-lists right now) and then use advanced `numpy` indexing/slicing:

```
>>> m = [[ 1.0, 0.0, -0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, -0.1, -0.1, 0.3, -0.2, -0.3],
...      [ 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0, -1.1, -0.6, 1.6, -1.2, -0.4],
...      [ 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, -2.0, -1.5, 2.7, -2.1, -0.8],
...      [-0.0, -0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 5.0, -0.6, -0.7, 0.9, -0.5, -0.6],
...      [-0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, 1.0, 6.0, 0.0, -0.3, -0.4, 0.4, -0.2]]
>>> M = np.array(m)
>>> M[:,-5:]
array([[-0.1, -0.1,  0.3, -0.2, -0.3],
       [-1.1, -0.6,  1.6, -1.2, -0.4],
       [-2. , -1.5,  2.7, -2.1, -0.8],
       [-0.6, -0.7,  0.9, -0.5, -0.6],
       [ 0. , -0.3, -0.4,  0.4, -0.2]])
```